# adding selfmade dependencies to a current maven-checkstyle plugin

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, artifactory

I need a to add maven-checkstyle-plugin to my master pom. In order to have a common place for checkstyle.xml for all users to use  my master pom, I need to add checkstyle.xml to a separate maven project called in my case build-tools-resources and then add this dependency to my maven-checkstyle-plugin as a dependency. Its not working because I am want this maven resource project to be locate under libs-snapshot-local but somehow maven is looking for at http://artifactory.kmd.dk/artifactory/plugins-snapshot, why ??? I want to decide where to keep my maven projects.
Can anyone explain?

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add libs-snapshot-local as a pluginrepository in your settings.xml then it works! :)